# syntastic not functioning: no errors

Tags: vim, macvim, syntastic

I've installed Pathogen, git clone'd the syntastic repo, and tried :Helptags in mvim. However, whenever I type :Helptags, I don't get an error but nothing at all happens. Any idea what might be going on?

UPDATE: I've tried again with Vundle (which is working fine with NERDTree and powerline) and am getting the following errors:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `:h :helptags`, this command (with an argument: `:Helptags /path/to/dir`) is used to index third party plugin's documentation. *It has nothing to do with the Syntastic plugin.*

If Pathogen is installed correctly, `:h syntastic` should open the documentation for Syntastic. Read it carefully, make sure you understand everything, try it and come back to us if you have any question.

Comment: Switched to Vundle and it worked. For future reference, try :SyntasticCheck or as @romainl said, :h syntastic. Thanks a bunch!

Another helpful [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457887/how-to-set-up-syntastic-for-vim) if you're having trouble.