# How to set up syntastic for vim?

Tags: vim, syntastic

So I git cloned the repository to `~/.vim/bundle` and had pathogen installed. I can be sure pathogen works fine since my other plugins in bundle are all working fine. After googling for a while, it seems that syntastic should work out of box for c code. I also checked that I have all the executables specified in `syntastic/syntax_checkers/c/`.

Here is a part of my .vimrc file:

```
" syntastic
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
let g:syntastic_disabled_filetypes=['html']
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
```

When I open a *.c file and do `:SyntasticCheck`, nothing happens. There is no errors complaining command not found, so syntastic is loaded. However, even if the *.c file that's currently opened contains errors syntax error, syntastic is not showing anything.

It is the first time I use syntastic so I don't really know the correct way to invoke it.

I also tried `:SyntasticCheck [c]` and I get the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>_22_UpdateErrors..<SNR>22_CacheErrors:
line 16:
E121: Undefined variable: checkers
E15: Invalid expression: checkers
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong and how to invoke syntastic?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand the reason, but when I re-installed the YouCompleteMe plugin for vim with `./install.sh --clang-completer`. Syntastic works like charm.

Comment: IIRC, YouCompleteMe and Syntastic have slightly overlapping features. You may double check YCM's doc for possible incompatibilities.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this to your vimrc:

```
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
```

(This is lifted straight from [my vimrc](https://github.com/EvanHahn/dotfiles/blob/0c63f509a83b4cc555c763639004e47bc800aea9/resources/vimrc#L266-L287), which has some other Syntastic settings if you'd like.)

Answer (score 0):

Installing clang and/or ctags packages fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

I did two things and then Syntastic started to behave as expected with JS files and ESlint. Can't tell which one did the trick:

1- In the project's directory ran `eslint --init`.

2- Started vim opening the file without the -S flag.

Before it failed silently, no errors and no diagnostics. This is how ESlint behaves when there is no configuration file.